# Use view variable in controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my controller I get all the entries from Athletes table, names, surnames etc... Save them in the array and pass them to my view. In my view file I then list all the entries using `foreach` . All the Athletes are listed fine...

However I want to check every Athlete and see if they exist in the table My Team! So in my `foreach` loop in my view I use this function

```
$this->my_team_model->exist($this->session->userdata("id"), $athletes[$i][6]) === TRUE
```

First parameter of exist() function is user id I get from session, second parameter is id of Athlete from Athletes table (`$athletes[$i][6]`).

So you see I really need that second Athlete id parameter! But I can only get it when the Athletes are listed one by one in my view. But I know I shouldn't use functions and logic in my view files. How can I do this in my controller?

Comment: do you any special case if it doesn't exist

Comment: I'm not familiar with Codeigniter specifically, but why can't you do this logic in your controller, and send the newly filtered data to the view?

Comment: may be you could re-structure your db query itself to filter the results..!

Comment: if you have the data in a view, you must have had it in your controller. so you are actually not using a 'view variable in controller', you are using a 'controller variable in view'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be using that same `foreach` loop in your controller and get the required data there itself, append the data to the array you pass to the view:

```
$array = $this->some_model->all_the_data_of_atheletes();
foreach( $array as $key => $eachAthelete ){
    $exists = $this->model->call_to_function( $this->session->userdata("id"), $eachAthelete['id'] );
    $array[$key]['exists']  = $exists;
}
$this->load->view('some_view', $array);
```

Now, in your view you will get an `exists` element for every iteration. Hope it helps you.